# hook into _gaq.push - google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I call _gaq.push in a lot of various places on my website (via scripts, flash etc). I have also set up my own local tracking service. Rather than call my service at the same point in my current code is it possible to create a function which calls my code everytime I call _gaq.push.

eg:

```
if(_gaq.push is called){
    $.get('http://mydomain.com/tracking_pixel.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture the `_gaq.push` function in a variable and then override it with your own function that calls original and then calls your code. Then anything that calls `_gaq.push` after you override it will call both. Example:

```
_gaq.basePush = _gaq.push;                           //capture the original
_gaq.push = function(/* params? */) {                //override it
    _gaq.basePush(/* params? */);                    //call the original
    $.get('http://mydomain.com/tracking_pixel.gif'); //call your function
};
```

Comment: Hm, this should probably be setup to run *after* ga.js has loaded (and `_gaq` has been converted from an array to a special object); otherwise it can seriously break Google Analytics. You can do that by wrapping this whole bit of code within `_gaq.push(function(){... });`

Comment: Brilliant. Been looking for a way to do this for ages!

Answer (score 2):

What about doing in reverse mode?

```
function doPush(){
   _gaq.push; //Do your push here
   $.get('http://mydomain.com/tracking_pixel.gif');
}
```

I ignore how to use _gaq.push, but you can allways parametrize doPush passing your needed arguments and call `_gaq.push` accordingly.

Comment: I like this one better because if ga.js loads after you have defined the function it won;t get overriden.